# Koa.js CORS in Firefox / Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, axios, koa

so I have a http GET request: `http://localhost:8080/api/toptracks`.

I installed the koa-cors package and set the cors to:

```
app.use(cors({
 origin: 'http://localhost:3000'
}));
```

the axios call is just a simple `axios.get(url).then(..)`

But it only returns in Chrome and not in Firefox, the network tab says something like `DNS resolution`, I cleared the cache.

Does anyone have clues how to solve it?

Comment: maybe FireFox not allowing the call to `localhost`.You would really learn of the true behavior when dealing in `devlopment` or `production` server

Comment: But having a call in the browser, it returns a JSON with the data

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix with the solution:

```
axios({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/track/toptracks?limit=250',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      json: true
    })
```